# Tab Bar исчезает после presentViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, iphone

После выполнения этого кода исчезает TabBarController:

```
ClientViewController *ViewController = [[ClientViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ClientViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.tabBarController presentViewController:ViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

ТабБар описан как проперти в AppDelegate.h.

Пробовал через наподобие:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate.tabBarController presentViewController:ViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Как правильно cделать, чтобы ТабБар не исчезал?

Comment: Попробовал добавить Navigation Controller.  Пример в AppDelegate:
UINavigationController * navigationController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:clientVC]; //для всех VC
Результат такой же.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот [тут](http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/window-uiviewcontroller-etc/uitabbarcontroller-view) разжовано

Comment: но там не описан такой случай: в одной из вьюшек есть кнопка(Например "Сохранить" или "Открыть") которая открывает другую вьюшку. Вот тут я теряю свой таббар контроллер.

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что вы делаете все программно без storyboard'а? как вы вызываете тот контролер по кнопке Например "Сохранить" или "Открыть"?

Comment: да, делаю все без сторибордов.
Если нажать на кнопку "Сохранить", то вызывается такой код:
DriverViewController *ViewController = [[DriverViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DriverViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:self.tabBarController animated:YES completion:nil];

Но я пробовал и такой код:
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [appDelegate.tabBarController presentViewController:ViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

Но не получается

Comment: Navigation controller не использую

Comment: без него никак. вот так у вас должно быть реализовано https://www.dropbox.com/s/0i9vz79q6ci9uv1/tabbarctrl.tiff

Comment: вот пример с Navigation controller  http://www.xdracco.net/howto-implement-uinavigationcontroller-uitabbarcontroller-programmatically/

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую добавить Navigation Controller.
Я вручную добавил на вьюшки Navigation Bar и все.